# Is there a limit to the number of domains that can be be mapped to a specific Cloud Run service?

Tags: google-cloud-run

The Resource limits for Cloud Run (https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas) lists a max number of SSL certificates (50) but not sure what "per top domain" or "per week" means in this context. Otherwise I have not seen this mentioned anywhere including the Cloud Run FAQ ;)

Answer (score 2):

Domain mapping map your service with your domain. It could be at the top domain (example.com) or at a subdomain (my-service.example.com). In both case, Google Cloud need to generate a valid SSL certificate for the root domain. Let's encrypt is used for this and the certificates are renewed regularly (at least every 90 days).

Thus, you can add up to 50 different top domains per week on Cloud Run service. It's global to your project, it's not for one service.

Comment: Thank-you! That helps to clarify the how and why of this Cloud Run limitation.

Comment: The work around for hitting this quota is to use a different mechanism for domain mappings, for example using a third party like Cloudflare.

Comment: @MarkM please, consider marking the above answer as correct, thanks!